# IIS - Build application without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012

I was recently given the source files for a Web Forms applications.  All the files, folders, ASPX, XML, cs and other source code files were present.  Except, there were no Visual Studio solution or project files.

Just the source files.

I was asked to modify and test the application with a text editor (notepad) and use IIS 7.0 to build and test the application.

How is this possible?

Comment: Why not download VS? There are free versions, such as VS Express, or if your company meets the requirements, Community edition.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods of website creation in Visual Studio, `Web Application` and `Web Site`. Refer to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx).

For your case, the project must be created using the `Web Site` method. This allows the site to be compiled on-the-fly, so you can just edit the source code with a text editor.